# how to do onclick child view(button) using OnItemClickListener in listview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, onclick, onitemclicklistener

can any one give me the example/ help me how to do onclick button to next activity.  My custom listview contains texts, button and scroll index.. i am geting problem in on click button..  i tried a lot from 3 days but no use.. if can any one say me how to do using onitemclickchildview(button(btnlist).. as i seen in some doc they told that listview is a parent and inside listview item/content/data
 is child.. i want child button(btnlist) to onclick. please help it.. thank u in advance.

homemplebrowview.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="100dip"
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
android:padding="5dip" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textColor="#663333"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/name"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="21dp"
        android:textColor="#666666"
        android:text="MRN:" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mrn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:textColor="#666666"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView4"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name"
        android:layout_marginLeft="63dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mrn"
        android:textColor="#666666"
        android:text="Actual Start Date:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/mrn"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/mrn"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:textColor="#666666"
        android:text="Age:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
        android:textColor="#666666"
        android:text="Gender"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_marginLeft="58dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:textColor="#666666"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/age"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/date"
        android:textColor="#666666"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gender"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/age"
        android:textColor="#666666"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/date"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/date"
        android:layout_marginLeft="119dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/date"
        android:textColor="#666666"
        android:text="Ward No:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/age"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/age"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
        android:textColor="#666666"
        android:text="Room No:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textColor="#666666"
        android:text="Bed No:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/wardno"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:textColor="#666666"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/roomno"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/wardno"
        android:textColor="#666666"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bedno"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/roomno"
        android:textColor="#666666"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/listbutton"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/name"
        android:layout_marginRight="43dp"   
        android:focusable="false"      
        android:text="Episode"
        android:textColor="#666666" />


</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
    SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, SearchView.OnCloseListener, OnClickListener{

private ListView listView;

private SearchView search;
EfficientAdapter objectAdapter; 
int textlength = 0;
private CheckBox checkStat, checkRoutine, checkTat;
private ArrayList<Patient> patientListArray;
private Patient patient;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.homempleb);
    Log.i("scan", " txtScanResult ");

    ActionItem nextItem = new ActionItem();
    final QuickAction quickAction = new QuickAction(this,
            QuickAction.VERTICAL);
    quickAction.addActionItem(nextItem);
    quickAction.setOnDismissListener(new QuickAction.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Dismissed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


  listView = (IndexableListView) findViewById(R.id.homelistView);
    //listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.homelistView);      
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    listView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
    //listView.setItemsCanFocus(true);
    listView.setClickable(false);
    listView.addStatesFromChildren();
    objectAdapter = new EfficientAdapter(this);     
    listView.setAdapter(objectAdapter);     


}



@Override
public boolean onClose() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return false;
}

    **

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "STAT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();       
    Intent next = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SeviceDetails.class);
   // Log.i("patient", " next "+ position + " onclickposition " + patientListArray.get(position).getMrnNumber());

    Log.i("DDDD ", patient.getMrnNumber());             


    System.out.println("patient"+ patient);
    startActivity(next);    

}

    **

  }
```

EfficientAdapter.java

```
    public class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements SectionIndexer {
IndexableListView mListView;
private String mSections = "#ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
ArrayList<Patient> patientListArray;

private Intent intent;
private Patient patient;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private Context context;
private int positions;
ViewHolder holder;
private String position;


public EfficientAdapter(Context context) {
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.context = context;

    String patientListJson = CountriesList.jsonData;
    JSONObject jssson;
    try {
        jssson = new JSONObject(patientListJson);
        patientListJson = jssson.getString("PostPatientDetailResult");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    JsonArray Jarray = parser.parse(patientListJson).getAsJsonArray();
    patientListArray = new ArrayList<Patient>();
    for (JsonElement obj : Jarray) {
        Patient patientList = gson.fromJson(obj, Patient.class);
        patientListArray.add(patientList);
    //  Log.i("patientList", patientListJson);

    }
}


public int getCount() {

    return patientListArray.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {

    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    this.positions = position;      
    View rowView = convertView;

    if (rowView  == null) { 
        Log.i("row", "Inside IF");
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.homemplebrowview, null); 

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.text1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.text2 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.mrn);
        holder.text3 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        holder.text4 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.age);
        holder.text5 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.gender);
        holder.text6 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.wardno);
        holder.text7 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.roomno);
        holder.text8 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.bedno);


    **  holder.btnList = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.listbutton);**



        rowView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    }
    Log.i("row", "Inside ELSE");

    holder.text1.setText(Util.formatN2H(patientListArray.get(position)
            .getName()));
    holder.text2.setText(patientListArray.get(position).getMrnNumber());
    holder.text3.setText(Util.formatN2H(patientListArray.get(position)
            .getRoom()));
    holder.text4.setText(Util.formatN2H(patientListArray.get(position)
            .getAge()));
    holder.text5.setText(Util.formatN2H(patientListArray.get(position)
            .getGender()));
    holder.text6.setText(Util.formatN2H(patientListArray.get(position)
            .getWard()));
    holder.text7.setText(Util.formatN2H(patientListArray.get(position)
            .getRoom()));
    holder.text8.setText(Util.formatN2H(patientListArray.get(position)
            .getBed()));        


**  holder.btnList.setOnClickListener(((MainActivity) context));  **

return rowView;
}       

static class ViewHolder {
    public Button btnList;
    public TextView text8;
    public TextView text7;
    public TextView text6;
    public TextView text5;
    public TextView text4;
    public TextView text1;
    public TextView text2;
    public TextView text3;
}

@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
}


public int getPositionForSection(int section) {
    sortMyData();

    Log.i("getPositionForSection", "section" + section);
    // If there is no item for current section, previous section will be
    // selected
    for (int i = section; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int j = 0; j < getCount(); j++) {
            if (i == 0) {

                Log.i("getPositionForSection- i", "section" + i);
                // For numeric section
                for (int k = 0; k <= 9; k++) {

                    if (StringMatcher.match(
                            String.valueOf(patientListArray.get(j)
                                    .getName().charAt(0)),
                            String.valueOf(k)))
                        Log.i("getPositionForSection- j", "section" + j);

                        return j;
                }
            } else {
                if (StringMatcher.match(
                        String.valueOf(patientListArray.get(j).getName()
                                .charAt(0)),
                        String.valueOf(mSections.charAt(i))))
                    return j;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
    return 0;
}

public Object[] getSections() {
    String[] sections = new String[mSections.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < mSections.length(); i++)
        sections[i] = String.valueOf(mSections.charAt(i));
    return sections;
}

/**
 * sorting the patientListArray data
 */
public void sortMyData() {
    // sorting the patientListArray data
    Collections.sort(patientListArray, new Comparator<Object>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Object k1, Object k2) {
            Patient p1 = (Patient) k1;
            Patient p2 = (Patient) k2;
            return p1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(p2.getName());
        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your code, its too tedious to go through. But i have had the same problems before and I solved it as follows. In your adapter you need to set the on click listener for that button and add a tag to it.

```
holder.btnList.setOnClickListener(((MyActivity) context));
```

Where `context` is the Context that you pass to the adapter and the `MyActivity` is whatever activity in which the click is to be handled. So when you click the button then the `MyActivity`'s on click listener will be called. You can also add tags to the holder object if you want any data to be passed. Then in your `MyActivity` where you implement the `onClickListener`. You handle whatever events you want in the `MyActivity`. Please post further doubts if you have any.

Comment: You are not supposed to use onItemClickListner, that wont work ni your case, because you are interested only on the click of a button in an item. Whereas onItemClickListner clicks the whole layout.

Comment: As per ur comment i have changed edited  code above can u check one.. changes i have highlighted as **

Comment: So when you click on the button the onClick of the MainActivity is not being called or what?

Comment: its is not going inside onclick itself.

Comment: Add this property to your Relative Layout android:descendantFocusability="blockDescendants" and check. The click of the button must be called.

Comment: no boss.. android:descendantFocusability="blockDescendants"  Its not working.. edit above code.. its not gng to onclick method itself

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17485/discussion-between-antrromet-and-raos)

Answer (score 0):

```
holder.btnList.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v){
     //youre code

     }
);
```